# Regex get IP addresses with qoutes

Tags: regex, web-applications

I have a text file with ip addresses, I need to extract all of the IP addresses inside of the file and save them into a database, the format of where the IP addresses are like this:

```
'heres an IP' = '134.981.652.32'
```

This is the regex I am using to find an IP address:

```
"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"
```

This works fine in finding IP addresses without the qoutes, I need to know how to find them when they include quotes like the above example. (I have no option of modifying what is contained in the file

Comment: Which programming language do you use? You need to include the quotes inside the regular expression but possibly need to escape them. Otherwise they might be taken for string boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes and remove the anchors:

```
"'(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good, but one problem, I need to save them without quotes, I do not have the option of programming, this gives me the ip address with quotes